# Why ampps is not selecting my db?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using ampps
The following is my config code. I've not given username and password in it.

```
$db_name="naatesam_FAMILY"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="user"; // Table name 


// Connect to server and select database.
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost", "", "")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
```

The output it shows is:

```
cannot select DB
```

I think without username and password it should work....
If anyhow they're required then please tell me how to set username and password for phpMyAdmin in ampps.

Comment: are you sure you have created the `naatesam_FAMILY` database?

Comment: Was about to ask the same... Check with phpMyAdmin if your database exists, and create it if not.

Comment: Surely I've created the database...I also created a table in it named user.

Comment: @DipaliPatil - dont use mysql_connect. Because mysql_connect is deprecated, use  mysqli_connect. For your question you got any solution?

Comment: @Fathah Rehman P Yes I've got a solution. Hardik's comment on his answer has given the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be :

```
$db_name="naatesam_FAMILY"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="user"; // Table name 


// Connect to server and select database.
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "mysql")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db($db_name, $conn)or die("cannot select DB");
```

Comment: I tried doing that too as I've read in other questions in stackoverflow that the default username is root and password is empty

Comment: @DipaliPatil Did you put $conn variable in to your mysql_select_db() function?

Comment: @DipaliPatil : Default MySQL root password is "mysql" for ampps so you need to add password "mysql" in your connection. See my edit i hope that will help for you.

Comment: Thanks hardik....default password for mysql in ampps is mysql...this solved my problem....pls edit your answer so that I can tick it

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost", "", "")or die("cannot connect");
```

change to

```
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "mysql")or die("cannot connect");
```

Comment: How do you know his mysql server user name is "root"??

Comment: I tried doing that too as I've read in other questions in stackoverflow that the default username is root and password is empty

Comment: @virendra Thanks for the generous help but hardik's solution worked.